# text1.Text as inputfield visual basic

Tags: c#, vb.net, loops

Hello i have an inputtextfield were i want to put figures for example 100 to have a script loop for 100 times, but im getting an error all the time. When putting a number at the place it does run normal, i'm trying to feed it with a number from the textbox.

```
for (var i = 0; i < (textBox2.Text); i++)
            {
code in here
}
```

Here's the error : Error    1   Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'

What am i doing wrong? Can someone help me??

Comment: Why did you tag this as VB.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give `textBox2.Text` although it would have number but it has type `string` and you need `integer`.

```
int result = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);      

for (var i = 0; i <result  ; i++)
{
    //Your code
}
```

Comment: i think i give a wrong example, because now the 100 times loop is exposed in the textbox. I would like to put the value 100 in the textbox and that need to be looped. How can i do that it doesnt work for me?

Comment: Check my code the number you give in textbox will decide the number of iterations of loop.

Answer (score 1):

`Check` if the text can be Parsed to an int `first and then proceed`. Following `int.TryParse()` method will return `true` if `textBox2.Text.Trim()` is an `int`

```
int limit;

if( int.TryParse(textBox2.Text.Trim(), out limit))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < limit ; i++)
    {
      //code in here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Int32.Parse()` method to convert the text in the textbox to an integer. The Text field is only an string and the compiler cannot figure out what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The value in `textBox2.Text` is of type string , you need to cast it to int.

This is done by cint() function

```
cint(textBox2.Text)
```

or Parse() method

```
Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
```

THe above two methods will work if you are sure the input string is valid that contains something like "123" rather than "absjsdfd".

```
for (var i = 0; i < Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text); i++)
{
//your code in here
}
```

To avoid throwing exception if invalid input is entered in textbox use a more robust function `Integer.TryParse()`

```
   int limit;
   bool valid = int.TryParse(textbox2.Text, out limit);
   if(valid)
     for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++)
     {
       //your code in here
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear, you're trying to compare an integer to a string value. That obviously won't work. You need first to cast the value from the textbox to integer type, than you can apply the condition for the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Int.Parse(txtFirst.Text);`

One thing, you seem to be a beginner, I want you to follow naming conventions in coding like `txt` prepended to the name of textbox, `lbl` for label and you can find more in your study material...

Comment: yes i'm a beginner ;) i really like the fast help i get over here ar Stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the `textBox2.Text` `String` to get an `int`. For instance:

```
int x = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, textbox2.text is a string and must be converted to a #n integer

```
for (var i = 0; i < int.Parse(textBox2.Text); i++)
        {
//code in here
}
```

However, i wound recommend you use a more appropriate control, such as a numeric Up Down:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value); i++)
        {
code in here
}
```